# Dependency Injection - .NET Core Windows Forms

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Silly DI question.  I've seen examples where DI is used for ASP.NET core and its great.

For .NET Core Windows Forms (yeah I know), but how is the DI object need to be passed around?  Is it possible to self reference the DI object so subforms have access to the DI object in their constructors?

Thanks

Comment: Inject as usually done with DI.

Comment: Show some code of how you understand it to work and where you are having issues.

Comment: inject the DI object that allows the creation of more objects?

Comment: That depends. Try to avoid service locator anti-pattern but there can also be factories that create the desired object.

Comment: Also try to avoid injecting run-time data via constructor injection.

Comment: ill code up with an example...in subforms...i want to avoid a static reference to the DI object...almost need a self reference